# Obtaining k-means centroids and outliers in python / pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, k-means, outliers

Does anyone know any simple algorithm in Python / PySpark to detect outliers in K-means clustering and to create a list or data frame of those outliers? I'm not sure how to obtain the centroids. I am using the following code:

```
n_clusters = 10

kmeans = KMeans(k = n_clusters, seed = 0)
model = kmeans.fit(Data.select("features"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`model.clusterCenters()` will give you the centroids.

To get the outliers, a straightforward way is to get the clusters with a size of 1.

Example:

```
data.show()
+-------------+
|     features|
+-------------+
|    [0.0,0.0]|
|    [1.0,1.0]|
|    [9.0,8.0]|
|    [8.0,9.0]|
|[100.0,100.0]|
+-------------+

from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans()
model = kmeans.fit(data)
model.summary.predictions.show()
+-------------+----------+
|     features|prediction|
+-------------+----------+
|    [0.0,0.0]|         0|
|    [1.0,1.0]|         0|
|    [9.0,8.0]|         0|
|    [8.0,9.0]|         0|
|[100.0,100.0]|         1|
+-------------+----------+

print(model.clusterCenters())
[array([4.5, 4.5]), array([100., 100.])]

print(model.summary.clusterSizes)
[4, 1]
```

```
# Get outliers with cluster size = 1
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
model.summary.predictions.filter(
    F.col('prediction').isin(
        [cluster_id for (cluster_id, size) in enumerate(model.summary.clusterSizes) if size == 1]
    )
).show()
+-------------+----------+
|     features|prediction|
+-------------+----------+
|[100.0,100.0]|         1|
+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: also checkout scipys kmeans modules https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2.html

Comment: @mck Just to make sure I understand: you define every cluster to have size = 1 and then you define as outliers the observations that are outside of that cluster of size 1? And the step where you define the size as 1 is "model.clusterCenters()
[array([4.5, 4.5]), array([100., 100.])]"?

Comment: @Johanna no, the size of clusters are determined  by the kmeans algorithm.  Outliers are defined as clusters with a size of 1.

Comment: @mck I'm really not sure I follow this process. I don't think I understand how it detects the outliers. Aren't the outliers detected by a certain distance treshold to the center?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Those outliers will not be a part of any other clusters, so it will form its own cluster with a size of 1. Does that clear your doubts?

Comment: Oh ok,  I think I understand now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any way to predict the outliers in each cluster? Meaning, if I have a cluster with 10 observations, and 2 aree farther from the centroid (despite being assigned to that same cluster), those 2 would be considered outliers? @mck

Comment: No, they are not outliers. They would not have been assigned to that cluster if they are far enough from the centroid.